# The children of a Transform are in reverse order

Tags: unity

I am making a simple 4-player turn-based card game.
At one point, a player can "open" his hand on the table. As the player does this, I want cards to be aligned in a way such that left side of each one is visible.

In my hand, the cards look like this.
[image]

When I carry them on the table, they look like this
[image]

Not only the order is reversed, which I wouldn't mind, but also the cards are not visible now.

This is how the green area looks like in the Inspector
[image]

I don't want cards to change shape to fill the area, and I also don't want them to go outside the green area.

When I unselect `Control Child Size`, the cards are aligned just as I want, but now they are too spread out and outside the green area.

Is there a way to achieve the behavior that I want?

Comment: Found the bug. It is because negative spacing is larger than a card's width.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the configuration is the negative spacing. The negative spacing exceeds the width of a card, and the card slides all the way back to the left side as a result.

To fix it, the spacing should be set to a value which is greater than -50 units.